# Has any research been done on Steve Krug recommendation of using 3 users for a Usability evaluation

Tags: usability, usability-study

In the book, Rocket Surgery Made Easy Steve Krug recommends using 3 users (contra Nielsens 5 users) for a usability evaluation. 
Has this ever been researched by anybody.?

Comment: Does he not give rationale in the book itself?

Comment: He gives an opinion. I am looking into wether anybody has actually tested his hypothesis against traditional usability evaluation methods, similar to those of Jakob Nielsen.

Comment: The whole point the book is making is that it's better to compromise on rigour in order to gain deliverability in a resource constrained team. He isn't aiming for the same goal as Jacob Nielsen, the two recommendations aren't necessarily comparable.

Comment: Thats my point. Without any objective data to back the claim up, it remains just a subjective opinion. From what I have researched, nobody has actually carried out an empirical study to back up the claim.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ideal number of candidates for user-testing](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4571/ideal-number-of-candidates-for-user-testing)

Comment: The other question ([Ideal number of candidates for user-testing](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4571/ideal-number-of-candidates-for-user-testing)) has answer(s) that point to research analysed in the book Measuring the User Experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Krug most likely recommendeds three users for the same reason that Nielsen recommendeds **no more than** five users: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/why-you-only-need-to-test-with-5-users/

**The law of diminishing returns** kicks in noticeably at around the third user, and after the fifth user the amount of new insights tails off significantly.

*The image above is from Nielsen's article.*

Comment: That image is very misleading; it's presenting an (informed) estimate as data.

Comment: Neilsens original article assumes multiple iterations.  It's 5 users per iteration, so 10 or 15 in total.

Answer (score 1):

I believe he recommends 3 users because it allows for a 9am-12pm testing period once a month, with a debrief at lunch. In other words, it makes it easy to form a usability HABIT.

Comment: Thanks for giving Krug's explanation. I think fynbo is asking if a second (possibly empirical) opinion on this recommendation exists.